# How to find an element followed by specific string from HTML data with JavaScript and alert it

Tags: javascript

I have some `HTML` data on a variable and I need to find a specific `HTML` element followed by some string.

Here is my code of `JavaScript`

```js
var complexArray = "<li>some content</li><li>Application Begin</li>"
var data = complexArray.querySelectorAll('li').text('Application Begin').parentElement;

alert (data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My expected output is : `<li>Application Begin</li>`

Comment: That is a string, not a DOM object. You cannot combine them both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues. You can't run DOM methods on a string like you're doing. You firslty need to parse your string to an DOM element. In order to parse it as a DOM element your string firstly needs to be valid HTML, this means it needs to be wrapped in `<ul>` (or `<ol>`) tags (as `<li>` tags can't be standalone). You can do this using a `DOMParser`:

```
var complexArray = "<li>some content</li><li>Application Begin</li>"
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<ul>${complexArray}</ul>`, "text/xml");
```

Now `doc` reprsents your DOM element, you can use DOM methods such as `querySelectorAll()`.

You also can't query text when using a query selector, however, you can use `.find()` to get a specific element from your found query results:

```js
var complexArray = "<li>some content</li><li>Application Begin</li>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<ul>${complexArray}</ul>`, "text/xml");

var data = [...doc.querySelectorAll('li')].find(({textContent:t}) => 
             t === "Application Begin"
           );

console.log(data.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or if you want to check if your string content contains your search string you can use `.includes`:

```js
var complexArray = "<ul><li>some content</li><li>Application Begin <b>30/07/2017</b></li></ul>";
var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(complexArray, "text/xml");

var data = [...doc.querySelectorAll('li')].find(({textContent:t}) => 
             t.includes("Application Begin")
           );

console.log(data.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I add more tag inside `li` than it's giving me error of undefined. I added the tag like: `<ul><li>some content</li><li>Application Begin <b>30/07/2017</b></li></ul>`

Comment: @SwapnilRajja thats because the content now equals `Application Begin <b>30/07/2017</b>` would you like it to check if it contains `"Application Begin"` instead?

Comment: @SwapnilRajja I've updated my answer to use `.includes` to check if the inner text has the search text

Comment: @NickParsonsThank you, you seems to be awesome in this. One thing more. If I have to get the exact value of that `<b>` tag. Actually it can be any tag inside `li` may be it can be `<b>` or may be it can be `<strong>`. I need to find that HTML data which is inside `<li>` and contains the text `Application Begins`

Comment: @SwapnilRajja something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/xk6b4ety/) ? I had to return an array of elements as there is a possibility that there are many elements within one `<li>`, thus this will give all those elements. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/xk6b4ety/1/) approach is a little more browser compatible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56829811/finding-string-and-its-related-elements-href-value

Answer (score 0):

Do u consider of using jQuery?

```
$("li:contains('Application Begin')").parent();
```

source: https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to it with jquery, you can do like this:

1. Convert html into DOM. DOMParser - like an option.
2. Use jQuery "contains" filter to find HTML element by it's content.

```
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var wrapper = parser.parseFromString(complexArray, "text/html");
    var data = $(wrapper).find('li:contains("Application Begin")');

    console.log(data[0].innerHTML); //Application Begin
```